# How to apply a commit to a folder without having the commit message applied to its files?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I renamed a folder and then committed the change.

All the files inside the folder were applied the same commit message.

How do I apply the commit to the folder,

without having the commit message applied to its files ?

[image: Screen copy of the issue]

Comment: The repeated commit messages in the file-list is something GitHub does - it has nothing to do with `git` itself.

Answer (score 5):

This question is based on a faulty premise.

Git doesn't "apply a commit message to files", it simply stores the commit message for each individual commit.

What you are seeing here is your git frontend (whatever renders the directory listing you screenshoted) trying to display the commit message for the last commit that touched a file.

And since moving a file in git is effectively the same as deleting and creating it with a different name the file will have been touched last by the renaming commit.

But again: there's absolutely no way to change how git stores these kinds of commit. The best you can do is find a tool that displays exactly what you want.

For example `git diff` has a feature to try to [find renames and consider them appropriately](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Mltngt), but that's a feature that `git diff` provides and doesn't change how the underlying commits are stored.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I apply the commit to the folder,

You can't, for the simple reason that there is no such thing as a folder in Git. There are not really files either, but closer: there are blobs with pathnames. So if you have blob *myFolder/a* and blob *myFolder/b* and you rename the folder to *myDirectory* in your world, in Git's world you have simply renamed both blobs to *myDirectory/a* and *myDirectory/b*.

(Actually it's trickier than that; you have deleted the blobs and created blobs that look just like them. But let's skip that.)

Everything else is mere external representation. Git doesn't attach commit messages to files or folders; it attaches them to commits. That's all Git knows about, commits. The file and folder icons in the screen shot, along with the commit messages next to them, are just an illusion painted to help you visualize things. And Git has nothing to do with that.
If you ask Git itself at the command line what is in its commits, you'll get a very different story.

Answer (score 1):

Under Git no more exists the concept of folder versioning, but only files.

So, a folder exists in your repo because it contains one or more tracked files.

For that reason each committed file share the same commit message.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* avoid the name changes from the files inside the renamed folder.  A file's actual name is its entire path from root (on Linux) or from the root of the drive (on Windows).  You will have to `git add` the entire folder to commit this change.

As a side note, it is generally not best practice to rename files and folders in Git, because sometimes the changes cannot be tracked through the history.  That is, were you to try to view the history of one of the renamed files, Git might not be able to piece together that the current file is related to its predecessor of a different name.

Comment: "it is generally not best practice to rename files and folders in Git" - citation needed. I think what you mean is "don't rename *and edit* files in the same commit. Instead: rename/move, commit, then edit and then commit"